# PHPUnit - REST API testing

Tags: rest, phpunit, guzzle

I have REST API written in php, i want to test it with phpunit.

I  wrote test like this, it works but response body was empty. I tested it with fiddler, it send response body.

Sorry for my english.

```
class ProgrammerControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

{
    public function testPOST()
    {   

    // create our http client (Guzzle)
    $client = new Guzzle\Http\Client();
    $response = $client->post("http://api.loc/v2/", array(
    'headers' => "User-Agent: Fiddler\r\n" .
                "Host: api.loc\r\n".
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                "Content-Length: 34\r\n",
    'body'    => array('kle' =>'sino','lat' => '41', 'long' => '69'),
    ));
    var_dump($response);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

this is my snippet ( it's in Get but it's the same )

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('http://192.168.99.100/v1/hello');
var_dump($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

result:

```
string(13) "{"bar":"foo"}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use built in method `call` of Laravel to test your controllers.

```
$response = $this->call('POST', '/api/v1.0/pages', $parameters);
$data = $response->getData();
```

Your `ProgrammerControllerTest` should extend from `TestCase`

Comment: I realize this is an old question and an old answer but the OP never said anything about what framework they are using .. to assume they are using laravel for a restful api is not a wise assumption to make and really does not answer his question....

Comment: @Logikos That may be the case, however I've been looking for a simple, low overhead example of a POST test in Laravel with PHPUnit with params... this, for me, answered *my* question.

Answer (score -1):

I know Amazon uses Guzzle to test AWS SDK, you can read more info at http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/testing/unit-testing.html

And also, don't hesitate to dig what others are using (such as Amazon, Facebook etc...), thats why open-source is so great!